# How to convert this regex to mysql posix

Tags: mysql, regex, posix

Please forgive me if this has answers already.

Being a total n00b with regex, I had a tough time getting good regex for this scenario:

I need to find if a string contains just letters, or letters and numbers from a MySQL table field...... eg. just get MET-KL2531910 and just get MET-IHLPOUJ without numbers (so MET-KL2531910 will not be included).

After some time, came up with these:

For MET-KL2531910

```
REGEXP '^(?=.*[-a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[-A-z0-9]+$'
```

For  MET-IHLPOUJ

```
REGEXP '^(?=.*[-A-z])[-A-z]+$'
```

However, since MySQL uses POSIX, these come out with this error

> Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Can anyone convert my regexes to POSIX regexes please.

Comment: The `(?=<...>)` clause in your expressions is called a positive lookahead. You're usually not allowed to use repetition operators like `*` within these. Is your requirement to match only those strings that are composed of just alphabets and a hyphen?

Comment: Yes, MET-[A-z] (so, only alphabets and a hyphen), and then MET-[A-z0-9] (alphabets, a hyphen and numbers). 2 different queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For MET-KL2531910
>   `REGEXP '^(?=.*[-a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[-A-z0-9]+$'`

You may use

```
^[-[:alnum:]]*([-[:alpha:]][-[:alnum:]]*[0-9]|[0-9][-[:alnum:]]*[-[:alpha:]])[-[:alnum:]]*$
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[-[:alnum:]]*` - 0+ hyphens or alphanumeric chars
- `(` - an alternative  group:

  - `[-[:alpha:]][-[:alnum:]]*[0-9]` - a hyphen/alpha char, 0+ alnum/`-` chars, a digit
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9][-[:alnum:]]*[-[:alpha:]]` - a digit, 0+ alnum/`-` chars, hyphen/alpha char
- `)` -  end of the alternation group
- `[-[:alnum:]]*` - 0+ hyphens or alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

> For  MET-IHLPOUJ
>   `REGEXP '^(?=.*[-A-z])[-A-z]+$'`

Here, you do not need the lookahead at all since you only match what you require, use

```
^[-[:alpha:]]+$
```

Here,

- `^` - matches the start of string
- `[-[:alpha:]]+` - matches 1 or more `-` or letters (=alpha chars)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thing that I forgot to include, records have 'WCP-', etc, so I only want to pull MET-... I just added MET after the ^'s. Apologies and thanks

Comment: See [`^MET-[-[:alnum:]]*([-[:alpha:]][-[:alnum:]]*[0-9]|[0-9][-[:alnum:]]*[-[:alpha:]])[-[:alnum:]]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/el5Qv8/2) and [`^MET-[-[:alpha:]]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/el5Qv8/3), just add `MET-` (and in the second one, replace `+` with `*`).

Comment: Also, as for `A-z`, see [*Why is this regex allowing a caret?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970)